# How to copy a request in soapui to a folder using groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am new in groovy and I want to have soap request which contains file which I want to be copy to a folder with a specific name when I am running my TestCase. My testcase will be created; first soap request disable and the groovy that will run and copy the soap. Can you please advise?

Comment: the description is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done.  It's really straight forward.  Took me two minutes to create an example of copying the request and response to files....

In your test, add a groovy step after the request of interest.  In the groovy, you need to reference the request and throw that at a file...

```
def rawRequest = context.expand( '${YOUR REQUEST NAME HERE#RawRequest}' )

def file1 = new File('c:/temp/groovy1.txt');
file1.write (rawRequest);

return rawRequest;
```

That will dump out your 'raw request' to a file.

Similarly, here's an example of saving the response of the request as XML.  You'll need a further groovy script step.  Again, really simple...

```
def responseAsXml = context.expand( '${YOUR REQUEST NAME#ResponseAsXml}' )


def file1 = new File('c:/temp/groovy2.xml');
file1.write (responseAsXml);
return responseAsXml;
```

You don't event need the return statements.  I just threw them in so I could check I am pulling data from the request step.

Obviously, you'll need to expand this to correctly name your files.  You should also wrap in in some execption checking to be sure there are no issues writign to file.

If you have the Pro version, you can right-click in the Groovy script and follow the 'Get Data' context menu to find the thing you want to dump into a file.

If you don't have the Pro version, then you'll need to look handcrafting the xpath to the node of interest.  Use log.info(someVar) to help verify you're getting down to the node of interest.

Comment: I took what you suggested but I am not sure about #RawRequest. if i am taking property from the level of testcase i i will have for example:<eh:originalAmount>${#TestCase#originalAmount}</eh:originalAmount>. now i have only the name of the request. what is RawRequest?

Comment: OK, in your test, you have the test step that actually calls a service.  In SoapUI GUI you should be able to edit your request to change some given value, you can do these change in a form or by changing the XML.  E.g. a name to search for.  This is what you are sending to the service.  'Raw Request' is a tab on the request test step which shows exactly what SoapUi is sending to the API you are testing.  In short, raw request is a property of the request object you are working with.

Comment: It is working fine if i have the request: def rawRequest = context.expand( '${#TestCase#File1}' )

def file1 = new File('c:/tem/groovy1.txt');
file1.write (rawRequest);                                                                                                                 But if i want to have the file not in property but in request which will be disable. can i do it?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am struggling to understand what you are trying to achieve by saying "But if i want to have the file not in property but in request which will be disable. can i do it?".

Comment: instead of context.expand( '${#TestCase#File1}' ) which the file will be located under propery in the level of the testcase, i want the file will be part of soap request which will be disable (will not run).

Comment: You want the actual SoapUi request to be populated with the contents of a file?

Comment: I want the SoapUi request to contains the contents of a file and the groovy will send this content as a file in a specific folder like you did -c:/temp/groovy2.xml

Comment: I attached screenshot how my test should be.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see any screenshots.

Comment: i am not able to upload screenshot and the only thing i can is shared link - enter image description here - click on it

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have a solution for this, but before I do, I ought to mention SoapUI's data driven test capabilities.  Have you looked at data sinks and data stores?

Data Sinks allow you to pull specific values out of a particular test step and save them to a file.  You can save values from a previous request or its response.

Further down in your tests, you create a data store, which links to the file you saved.  The data store object allows you to map columns in your saved file.  Once that is set up, you create another request with a standard request, but you can then substitute hard coded values with a value from the data store.

This allows you to create one single test, that can then be called with each row of data in your data store.

For example, you are testing a 'create user' web service.  The Web Service has lots of business rules that need to be applied.  E.g. Surname not be blank.
You could write a separate SoapUI test to verify that each business rule works, but what would be better would be to create a data store that contains the parameters for each test including the expected result.

Using the data store and data loop, you can call you result test step for each row in your data store.

Example test data

[image: Example test data]

Example Flow

[image: Example flow]

All steps between the data source and data loop are called for every row in the data source.

IMHO, these are brilliant as it reduces the number of tests to maintain within SoapUI and if you need to added further scenarios, e.g. no email address, then you just update the spreadsheet your data source is linked to.

Back to pulling the contents of a file into a SoapUi request....

Example flow....

[image]

The first step is the original request to some web service.

The second step writes the request to a text file...

```
def rawRequest = context.expand( '${REST Test Request#RawRequest}' )

def file1 = new File('c:/temp/groovy1.txt');
file1.write (rawRequest);
return rawRequest;
```

The third step use Groovy to read a file...

```
def file1 = new File('c:/temp/groovy1.txt');

return file1.text;
```

Finally, the last step is the request with the file contents.  To do this, create the request as normal. In the request tab, delete the body of the request and the use ${} to pull string that the Groovy Script read from file.

```
${Load Saved Request from File - Groovy Script#result#}
```

When the test runs, the Grrovy in Step 3, reads the file, but doesn't do anything with it.  When SoapUI attempts to run Step 4, it sees the ${} instruction and gets the string returned by the Step 3 groovy script.

So now, you have examples of how to write a request to file, read a file and squirt the contents of a file into a request.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen in the past other solution which i still want use it instaed of using rest methods. I think i can have an option so have first THE SOAP request as diasable step and step 2 the groovy as in the screenshot: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1jQd.png)

Comment: SOAP request or REST request, it makes no difference, the approach will work to save the request to file or to pull in a request from file.  My example might have shown a REST request, but it was only an example.  It's the Groovy script that's important for writing to and reading from file.

Comment: def rawRequest = context.expand('${SOAP}')

def file1 = new File('c:/tem/groovy1.txt');
file1.write (rawRequest);
return rawRequest;   This script creating 0 kb file...I am not following what you are suggesting.

Comment: Assuming SOAP is the name of the request that you want to write to file... you also need to specify the property you want to write to file.  You asked for the request payload, the property name for that is RawRequest, so for you, try context.expand('${SOAP#RawRequest}').

Comment: The SOAP is the name of the request contains my input of xml.  I wanted it to be copy to a folder as an xml file. if i am using your code it is working ok only if i have my input in propery in the level of test case - def rawRequest = context.expand('${#TestCase#RawRequest}'). I want to have the first option that the xml will be located in request and not in property. why i want it to be like that? if i have normal request which i am sending by service, i can have inside the request properties from the TestCase which are changed while running - <eh:originalAmount>${#TestCase#originalAmount}

Comment: So, once you have the xml in a file, you want that xml imported into a test step from the file and not by using properties?

Comment: I dont want it to be imported to no where. My testing is to copy a file to folder which i have listener that moving it to other folder. I just want to have xml located it my test under soap request and this one to be copy as xml file under specific folder. I also would like to have the option of properties inside the input of the request in order to control the input of those properties in a level of test suite of testcase.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm really trying to help, but you have completely lost me now.

Comment: If you can explain in clearer terms and may include some screenshots, then I can probably help.

Comment: I attached screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

```
def cur_Time = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone('IST')).format("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH-mm-ss z")

new File("C:\\Users\\SHILPA\\Desktop\\soapUIxls\\RequestPayload"+cur_Time+".doc").write(context.rawRequest)
```

It will help to capture request payload with dynamic values passed.

So you can see request and response payloads in soapUIlog

```
log.info(context.response)
log.info(context.rawRequest)
```